# what is the input type of classOf

Tags: scala, types

I am wondering what type do I put in place of XXX

```
def registerClass(cl:XXX) = kryo.register(classOf[cl])
```

EDIT: For why I want to do this.

I have to register many classes using the above code. I wanted to remove the duplication of calling kyro.register several times, hoping to write code like below:

```
 Seq(com.mypackage.class1,com.mypackage.class2,com.mypackage.class3).foreach(registerClass)
```

Another question, can I pass String instead? and convert it somehow to a class in registerClass?

```
Seq("com.mypackage.class1","com.mypackage.class2").foreach(registerClass)
```

EDIT 2:
When I write com.mypackage.class1, it means any class defined in my source. So if I create a class

```
package com.mypackage.model

class Dummy(val ids:Seq[Int],val name:String)
```

I would provide com.mypackage.model.Dummy as input
So,

```
kryo.register(classOf[com.mypackage.model.Dummy])
```

Kryo is a Java Serialization library. The signature of the register class is

```
register(Class type)
```

Comment: Can you show what `com.mypackage.class1` looks like? And what is the method signature of `register` on `kryo`?

Comment: If `class1` is a class definition, I suspect you'll have to use EECOLOR's solution of `Seq(classOf[com.mypackage.class1],...).foreach(registerClass)`

Comment: @KristianDomagala created EDIT 2 to clarify further.

Comment: In that case, my second comment stands. You technically could use strings and convert them to a `Class[_]` using `java.lang.Class.forName(...)`, but that's prone to all the problems associated with reflection.

Comment: thanks Kristian,I agree with you EECOLOR has given the best solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
def registerClass(cl:Class[_]) = kryo.register(cl)
```

And then call it like this:

```
registerClass(classOf[Int])
```

Answer (score 1):

The type parameter to `classOf` needs to be known at compile time. Without knowing more about what you're trying to do, is there any reason you can't use:

```
def registerClass(cl:XXX) = kryo.register(cl.getClass)
```

Comment: edited the question to help you understand what I am trying to do